# DateTime change format error

Tags: c#, datetime

```
var test = DateTime.ParseExact("Feb  4 2014 12:00AM", "MMM  dd yyyy HH:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyy-MM-dd");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(test);
```

So I got this code. What I am trying to do is to convert `Feb  4 2014 12:00AM` to `2014-02-04`.

The error I get is this one :

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> > Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

But I can't find out what's wrong. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of issues with your format. It should be:

```
"MMM  d yyyy hh:mmtt"
```

Use:

- single `d` for date part, as it can accommodate single and double digit dates, your current specifier `dd` would expect single digit date part to start with zero like `04`. Single `d` can be used to parse both single/double digits dates.
- use `hh` instead of `HH` for hour part, since you have `AM` in the string that means your hour format is `12` hours and not `24` hours.

So your code should be:

```
var test = DateTime.ParseExact("Feb  4 2014 12:00AM", "MMM  d yyyy hh:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also tried with the single `d` but didn't thought the problem came from the `hh`. I read somewhere the opposite and thought it was `HH` for `12` hours and not `24`. Thanx buddy :)

Comment: Still get exceptions when the date is this format : `Apr 17 2014 12:00AM` does the `d` manage only single number days ?

Comment: Finally found the problem. So apparently when you turn to String a Date from an SQL reauest. It does the following :
- if the day number is `4` it will give you ` 4` instead of just `4`.
- if the day is `17` it gives you juste `17`. 
I use the Replace function to work it out.